# Avoid repetition in BLoCs and RxDart

Tags: dart, flutter

hopefully I can make myself clear.

After video and tutorials, I found this way to have some widgets to input data to the bloc (valueSetting) and some others to get this data (value).

What I am asking is if there is a better way (there has to be..). I want to avoid the need to have 4 variables for just 1 real value shared between widgets.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';

class BlocExample {
  final _valueSettingController = StreamController<bool>();

  // object use by widget to push data
  Sink<bool> get valueSetting => _valueSettingController.sink;

  final _value = BehaviorSubject<bool>(seedValue: false);

  // object used by widget to get data
  Stream<bool> get value => _value.stream;

  BlocExample() {
    _valueSettingController.stream.listen(_value.add);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _value.close();
    _valueSettingController.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, let me say that you can remove the private variables by using a custom factory constructor. Here's an example:

```
class MyBloc {
  final Sink<bool> input;
  final Stream<bool> output;
  final VoidCallback _dispose;

  MyBloc._({this.input, this.output, VoidCallback dispose}) : _dispose = dispose;

  factory MyBloc() {
    final mainController = BehaviorSubject(seedValue: false);
    return MyBloc._(
      input: mainController.sink,
      output: mainController.stream,
      dispose: () {
        mainController.close();
      },
    );
  }

  void dispose() {
    _dispose();
  }
}
```

Secondly, the problem you're trying to solve is actually not a problem. While it seems at first that there's a lot of duplicates; in reality they serve different purposes.

In many situations, your `Stream` will be more than just `_controller.stream`. For example, for whatever reason you may want to transform the value before exposing it:

```
final mainController = BehaviorSubject(seedValue: false);

final Stream<bool> output = mainController.map((foo) => !foo);
```

This code makes that the `output` stream reverses the value of everything passed to `mainController.sink`

**But in my situation this is not the case. So why 3 variables that point to the same thing?**

The fact that in your situation, your controller is both the sink and stream without transformation is an implementation detail and may be subject to changes.

By exposing `Sink`/`Stream` as done before, you actually abstract this implementation detail. So that in the future if your stream needs custom operations; no change will be required by your UI.

This is not necessary. But recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :)

```
  enum STREAM_GROUP {
    TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3
  }

  class BlocExample {

        Map<STREAM_GROUP, StreamController<bool>> groups = new Map();

        Stream<bool> getValue(STREAM_GROUP type){
          return groups[type].stream;
        }
        Sink<bool> getValueSetting(STREAM_GROUP type){
          return groups[type].sink;
        }

        BlocExample() {
          groups[STREAM_GROUP.TYPE1] = StreamController<bool>();
          groups[STREAM_GROUP.TYPE2] = StreamController<bool>();
          groups[STREAM_GROUP.TYPE3] = StreamController<bool>();

          groups.forEach((groupType, streamController){
              final currentValue = BehaviorSubject<bool>(seedValue: false);
              streamController.stream.listen(currentValue.add);
          });


        }

        void dispose() {
           groups.forEach((groupType, streamController){
              streamController.close();
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: That's the same thing though. This doesn't reduce the number of variables.

Comment: not really, using his approach he will have to write his number of vars multiplied by the number of elements.

Comment: You still have 2 getter per controller though

Comment: we can fixe that, now think about 10 boolean fields. it doesn't increment the number of vars , just adding new enums values into the constructor would be fine.

Comment: But not all sink/streams are for the same type. You'd need to have one enum and map per type. And you don't want to force your app to use the enum to access fields.

Comment: yes, you are right, it only works for inputs of the same type.